# Integration of product of lower incomplete gamma function with exponential function?

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, gamma-function

I am stuck in getting the following integral that involves  product of lower incomplete gamma function with exponential function.

$\int_0^{\infty}\gamma(a,b\cdot q) e^{-K\cdot q}\text{dq}$

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Note that $a,b$ and $K$ are constants.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^\infty\gamma(ab,q)\exp(-Kq)dq$$

---

$$
u=\gamma(ab,q)=\int_q^\infty t^{ab-1}e^{-t}dt\Rightarrow u'=-q^{ab-1}e^{-q}
\\v'=\exp(-Kq)\Rightarrow v=-\exp(-Kq)/K
$$
This is just integration by parts and leaves us with:
$$I=\left.uv\right|_{0}^\infty-\int_0^\infty u'v \,dq$$
and this integral will be:
$$\frac1K\int_0^\infty q^{ab-1}e^{-(K+1)q}dq$$
and now this is just the full gamma function. Just make sure to carefully evaluate $uv$

Comment: But why did you changed $\gamma(a,b\cdot q)$ to $\gamma(a\cdot b,q)$?

Comment: @taru ah sorry was just a typo